# Setting NavigationController's NavigationBar translucent property to false causes extra padding

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6.1

There appears to be extra padding at the top of the root content view when the `translucent = false` property is set on the NavigationController's NavigationBar (programatically or via the StoryBoard).

I've tried adjusting the scroll view insets but to no avail. `translucent = true` doesn't cause this problem.

Any ideas why this is happening and what the easiest way to resolve it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah-ha - got there in the end. When *not* using a translucent navigation bar you need to ensure that both `adjusts scroll view insets` and `extend edges under opaque bars` are set to `true` on all your view controllers.

Here are the StoryBoard settings:

[image]

Comment: self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true did it for me!

Comment: time saver thans a lot!