# Swift - NavigationBar issue with SearchController

Tags: swift2, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I am having a problem with the `NavigationBar` when used with the `SearchController`.

If the `NavigationBar` `translucent property` is set to false the `NavigationBar` goes out of the screen when the `SearchController` is active. If the `translucent property` is set to true it works fine.

How could I fix it?

Code and Images below:

Swift file

```
import UIKit

class SelecionaPaisTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    //MARK: - Propriedades
    var paises = [PaisCodigo]()
    var paisesFiltrado = [PaisCodigo]()

    var controladorDeBusca: UISearchController!

    //MARK: - Métodos reescritos da View
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Dados dos países
        carregaDadosPaises()

        //Carrega configuração do SearchController
        configurarControladorDeBusca()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Métodos reescritos da Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if controladorDeBusca.active {
            return paisesFiltrado.count
        } else {
            return paises.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PaisCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PaisCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let pais: PaisCodigo

        if controladorDeBusca.active {
            pais = paisesFiltrado[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            pais = paises[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = pais.nome + " (+" + String(pais.codigo) + ")"

        if pais.nome != pais.nomeIngles {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = pais.nomeIngles
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        }

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: - Métodos do UISearchResultsUpdating
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        //paisesFiltrado.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    }

    //MARK: - Métodos
    func carregaDadosPaises() {
        let pais1 = PaisCodigo(nome: "Brasil", nomeIngles: "Brazil", codigo: 55)
        let pais2 = PaisCodigo(nome: "United States", nomeIngles: "United States", codigo: 1)

        paises += [pais1, pais2]

        //paisesTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func configurarControladorDeBusca() {
        //Configura Controlador de Busca
        controladorDeBusca = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controladorDeBusca.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controladorDeBusca.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true

        //Configura a barra do Controlador de busca
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.placeholder = "Search country"
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.barTintColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.translucent = true

        //UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //let atts = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

        let atts = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"GillSans-Bold", size:16)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleDouble.rawValue
        ]

        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes(atts, forState: .Normal)

        //Adiciona a barra do Controlador de Busca a Table View
        tableView.tableHeaderView = controladorDeBusca.searchBar
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When not using a `translucent` `NavigationBar` you need to ensure that both `adjusts scroll view insets` and `extend edges under opaque bars` are set to true on your `ViewController`.

Link of the answer:
[Setting NavigationController's NavigationBar translucent property to false causes extra padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710926/setting-navigationcontrollers-navigationbar-translucent-property-to-false-cause)